# How to webpack bundle a file which requires another file at runtime depending upon command line argument?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Consider a very simple application with the project structure

```
-- package.json
-- webpack.config.js
-- src
    |---index.js
    |---runner.js
```

The index.js takes in command line arg to require a file, at runtime. Here is index.js:

```
function requireAtRuntime(filename){
    const runner = require(filename);
    runner.run()
}

var filename = process.argv[2];
requireAtRuntime(filename);
```

runner.js

```
function run(){
    console.log("hello world");
}

exports.run = run
```

package.json contains the script:

```
//
scripts :{  
  "start" : "node src/index.js ./runner.js"
}
```

This start scripts work well. Now the issue if I want to webpack index.js, runner.js is not included as it dependency and the bundle throws the error when i try to run

```
node dist/main.js path/to/runner.js
Error: Cannot find module 'path/to/runner.js'
```

How do I build my webpack so that it can too take filename as command line argument and require it during runtime (or store it before somewhere)?

Comment: Webpack is a bundler, at the and, your local dependencies won't have the same paths as they bundled together, hence the nam bundler

Comment: Require every possible dynamic js file somewhere within your code, maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to provide some kind of hint to webpack around what all files may be dynamically required. Lets assume we have multiple runners. We need to put all of them in a folder like shown below

```
-- package.json
-- webpack.config.js
-- src
    |---index.js
    |---runners
             |---runner1.js
             |---runner2.js
```

Now we need to change the `requireAtRuntime()` function.

`index.js`:

```
function requireAtRuntime(filename){
    const runner = require(`./runners/${filename)`);
    runner.run()
}

var filename = process.argv[2];
requireAtRuntime(filename);
```

This will make webpack to fetch all the files in runners and bundle them during compile time.

Now we can run it as

`node src/index.js runner1/2` (before bundling) or

`node dist/main.js runner1/2` (after bundling)

Answer (score 0):

you have to declaratively specify runner.js as externals, so that webpack won't bundle it at compile time

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: Nope, not bundling is not the issue here. It anyways wont bundle at compile time because it has no idea about the runner file at compile time, the issue is regarding how to expose the runner at runtime